# How to dynamically insert new top bar and shift all original content down?

Tags: javascript, css

My goal is to 1) load a new "top bar" element on an arbitrary site using JS bookmarklet; 2) have the top bar pinned to the top; 3) push the original content down.

Is there a **reliable** way to do it with CSS/JS that would work with all sites?

Edit: This is what I tried: jQuery.wrapInner() and prepend() to first, wrap the existing body content into a new DIV, and second, to insert another new DIV with fixed position to the top. I already ran into issues with jQuery.wrapInner() re-evaluating JavaScripts twice.

One alternative I can think of is to proxy the original page through my website and have the original as iFrame (just like Digg does).

Comment: what have you tried? With what you've provided, the current answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done reliably because JavaScript gets re-evaluated when injected into the host page. For some host pages it won't matter, for others it creates a complete mess. Now I understand why iFrame approach is used as much as it is.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to wrapp the original content in a div using jquery and then set `position:absolute;
 top: 20px;` 
if your topbar is 20 px high. I can't really think of a case where this won't work...